# gigabyte Z370 HD3 + Samsung EVO 970 won't install Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, motherboard

Newly assembled system:

- Gigabyte Z370 HD3 V1.0 motherboard
- Intel i7-8700 CPU
- 2x DDR4-3200 16GB RAM (F4-3200C16D-32GVK)
- Samsung EVO 970 500 GB M.2 SSD (MZ-V6E500)
- Thermaltake TR2 S 500 W PSU (TRS-0500P-2)
- Deepcool Tesseract case (seems doesn't matter)

All components come new, unpacked.

Windows 10 Pro installation failed at the step "Getting files ready for installation." when about 70-80% complete.

I used both the original Windows 10 Pro DVD and a USB stick prepared by a Microsoft tool; the result is the same.

I tried to use the pre-installation SATA driver from the Gigabyte website.
Once I installed this driver at the step "Where do you want to install Windows", my M2 drive had disappeared from the list.

The same situation repeated with another set of components.

By the way, when I try the same set of components but with an ASUS Z370-P motherboard, there is no problem with Windows 10 installation.

I still need to assemble some systems with Gigabyte motherboards.

Update: It was easy to install Windows 10 on the SATA SSD. Same conditions: Gigabyte motherboard, but SATA SSD instead of M2 SSD.

Any suggestion what to do in order to install Window properly?

Comment: What did you use to make the installation media?  Edit this vital information into the question body.

Comment: Did you use DISKPART to clean the M.2 drive before installation? Please click on [edit] above to the left and advise.

Comment: Did not use DISKPART, by the way it's not important information now. Problem has been caused by hardware. Please read answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! 
It was the hardware problem.

M2 SSD works unstable at low power supply voltage condition.

Found that PSU output drop down from 3,3 V output to 2,8 V while no or very small current consumption from 5V line. Because M2 SSD at Gigabyte motherboard had powered directly from the 3,3V line come from PSU , which becomes less 2,8 V after minute or little more working, then SSD refuse to work properly. Strange that PSU still keep "Power Good" status in condition when one voltage definitely fail.

If add some load at +5V line (say, common HDD), 3,3V output becomes stable and no issues during Windows installation and further work.

Comment: Interesting. If the PSU manufacturer does not specify a minimum required current for the 5V rail, I would suspect that the unit has a problem.